# What is NCHW Format?

Tags: object, nvidia, detection, inference, nvidia-jetson

Can someone explain to me what is NHCW format? I am working with the Jenson Inference library and for object detection the first step is called "Pre-Process" and it converts the image to NCHW format, but I don't know what this format is.

Answer (score 12):

**NCHW** stands for:

batch **N**, channels **C**, depth **D**, height **H**, width **W**

It is a way to store multidimensional arrays / data frames / matrix into memory, which can be considered as a 1-D array. You may have a look to [this link](https://oneapi-src.github.io/oneDNN/dev_guide_understanding_memory_formats.html) for further information. There also exist [variants](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/issues/5778) of this format with different ways of "casting" the multidimensional data into one.

Answer (score 2):

**NCHW** is an acronym describing the order of the axes in a tensor containing image data samples.

- **N**: Number of data samples.

  **C**: Image channels. A red-green-blue (RGB) image will have 3 channels.

  **H**: Image height.

  **W**: Image width.

[Source](https://machinelearning.wtf/terms/nchw/)